# Typeahead.js / Bloodhound display just one result

Tags: javascript, json, typeahead.js, bloodhound

My Typeahead.js / Bloodhound (**0.11.1**) doesn't work as expected. Out of the long list of json results provided, only some are displayed as suggestions.

For example, if I type `los` in my field, I get only `Lostorf` and nothing else, when there should be 4 selectable items displayed.

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="remote">
<input class="typeahead" type="text">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var searchablePlaces    = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer      : Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace("term"),
    queryTokenizer      : Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote              : {
        url             : 'http://www.example.com/autocomplete/%QUERY/',
        wildcard        : '%QUERY',
        filter          : function(response) { return response.data.results; }
      },
    limit               : 10
});

searchablePlaces.initialize();

$('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(
{
    hint            : true,
    highlight       : true,
    minLength       : 2
},
{
    name            : 'searchable-places',
    displayKey      : "term",
    source          : searchablePlaces.ttAdapter()
})
```

**Json**

```
{
    "data": {
        "query": "los",
        "count": 4,
        "results": {
            "1": {
                "term": "Losanna"
            },
            "2": {
                "term": "Losone"
            },
            "3": {
                "term": "Lostallo"
            },
            "4": {
                "term": "Lostorf"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do you see something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Possibile cause: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1218

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is to confirm that the issue is caused by this typehaead bug: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1218

As suggested by joekur in the issue report, I solved replacing this:

```
rendered += suggestions.length;
that._append(query, suggestions.slice(0, that.limit - rendered));
```

With this:

```
suggestions = suggestions.slice(0, that.limit - rendered);
rendered += suggestions.length;
that._append(query, suggestions);
```

I marked my own question as duplicate of this: [TypeAhead.js and Bloodhound showing an odd number of results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125410/typeahead-js-and-bloodhound-showing-an-odd-number-of-results) It's the same problem, I just cannot find it before due to different wording

HTH.

Comment: I actually didn't have to replace the code, only add `limit:10` to typeahead and my results started showing.

Comment: Thank you! It did solve the issue.
That was driving me crazy for like 2 hours!

Comment: Its still the issue so you code really helped. was about to go mad :)

Comment: Thanks Dr you answer also solve my problem.

Comment: I tried the @rosskevin on Github issue and it works well. "I actually didn't have to replace the code, only add limit:10 to typeahead and my results started showing."

Comment: I had the issue once I added the limit: 10.  I wanted to keep limit: 10 (rather than the default 5), so I did the line swap so that rendered is incremented once the items have been added. I haven't seen any negative side effects.

Comment: Twitter have abandoned the project, [corejs-typeahead](https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js) is a maintained fork that fixes this bug.